# Is there any way to download a ticket from Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, download, share, ticket-system

My colleague does not have access to the Azure DevOps ticket. I was thinking is there a better way to send the ticket to the colleague instead of making screenshots of the requirements? There is an outage or something with the Azure DevOps, that is why my colleague does not see the ticket. It is not a permission issue.

Comment: *It is not a permissions issue.* What are you basing that on? It is almost certainly a permission issue.

Comment: @DanielMann, it was a certificate issue. Almost the whole team had Azure DevOps broken. For some reasons it still worked for a few people, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try emailing this ticket to your colleague to check if it can be delivered.

[image: send work item]